# Issues related to library

Tags: python-3.x, linkedin-api, forecasting

I am using a forecating library named as greykite from linkedin but After the update in the documentation, we are unable to even load the libraries for our work. We have tried using the same in anaconda's jupyter notebook and google colab.

Also, I am uploading the image for the same in the question so that one of you can help me out. I have taken the exactly same code which is mentioned in there documentation.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jE2rF.png)

Libraries should have been worked properly and should let me allow to work further

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.